# Test validity of linear regression model - R

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, cross-validation, predictive-models

I have divided my dataset into train and test set, and I have run a linear regression on the train set.
However, how do I understand how well my model performs on the test set?

My code is:

```
linearMod <- lm(y ~ x1+ x2+ x3, data = train_df)
summary(linearMod)

predicted <- predict(linearMod, test_df)
```

Sorry for the probably stupid question but I am new to data analysis

Comment: Compare the "true" `y` values in `test_df` with the `predicted`values to see, if they are close or not. RMSE comes to mind as in `sqrt(sum(test_df$y-predicted)^2)` or simply a residuals plot as in `plot(test_df$y, test_df$y - predicted)` and `hist(test_df$y - predicted)` to see if the residuals' sizes are acceptable for your predictive purposes..

Answer (score 1):

From your training data, you have built a model (in this case a linear one). Say you have $n_{test}$ number of samples in your test set, each with the true value for $y$ and the values for the variables $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$.

For each sample in your test set, the `predict` function in R gives you the output of your model, given a specific input. So for sample number $i$ in your test set, with values $x_{1i}, x_{2i}, x_{3i}$, the output is $\hat{y}_i$, the predicted value given your model. If the input is a data set of size $n_{test}$, then the output is the vector of predicted values.

To evaluate how well your model fits these data, you investigate the difference between the predicted values $\hat{y}_i$'s and the true values $y_i$'s. This is commonly done by root mean squared error (RMSE), in R you can use the function `rmse()` from the Metrics package.

Comment: That strategy does not assess goodness of fit.  It only measures how well an oversimplified model happens to explain the response variable.  To gauge goodness of fit you need to compare the naive model with a model that is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Split sample validation is a very inefficient approach and requires large test and training sample sizes.  It’s also not a good approach to fit the simplest model and hope for the best, then be surprised when it doesn’t fit.  Instead, make use of subject matter expertise and pre-specify a model that is more likely to fit.  For example, relax linearity assumptions using regression splines.  Keep in mind the effective sample size when figuring how many parameters you can specify in the model.  Lots of details are [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/multivar).